# How to structure a database with varying levels of connected tables/models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, data-structures

I am structuring a database that stores religious text books. My issue is each text has a varying number of levels.

Example:

```
Bible -> Books -> Chapters -> Verses

Quran -> Chapters -> Verses

Pali Canon -> Books -> Sub_Books -> Chapters -> Sub_chapters -> Verses
```

And I presume other texts will have even more variation. What is the best way to structure something like this so my database and code can be more flexible and support these "sub-models"

Thanks.

It's written with Ruby on Rails, so any answers tailored to that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Building a hierachy can be done quite simply with [self joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins)

```
books:
    id [integer, primary key, auto-index]
    parent_book_id: [integer, foreign-key self joins books]

chapters:
    id [integer, primary key, auto-index]
    book_id: [integer, foreign-key, joins books]
    parent_chapter_id: [integer, foreign-key self joins chapters] 

verses:
    id [integer, primary key, auto-index]
    chapter_id: [integer, foreign-key, joins chapters]
    parent_verse_id: [integer, foreign-key self joins verses]
```

The models:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sub_books, class_name: "Book", foreign_key: "parent_book_id"
    belongs_to :parent_book, class_name: "book"
    has_many :chapters
    has_many :verses, though: :chapters
end

class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sub_chapters, class_name: "Chapter", foreign_key: "parent_chapter_id"
    belongs_to :parent_chapter, class_name: "Chapter"
    belongs_to :book
    has_many :verses
end

class Verse < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sub_verses, class_name: "Verse", foreign_key: "parent_verse_id"
    belongs_to :parent_verse, class_name: "Verse"
    belongs_to :chapter
    belongs_to :book, though: :chapter
end
```

Comment: Note that this is just a quick sketch - the code won't actually run.